# import implicit conversions without instance of SparkSession

Tags: scala, apache-spark, implicits

My Spark-Code is cluttered with code like this

```
object Transformations {   
  def selectI(df:DataFrame) : DataFrame = {    
    // needed to use $ to generate ColumnName
    import df.sparkSession.implicits._

    df.select($"i")
  }
}
```

or alternatively

```
object Transformations {   
  def selectI(df:DataFrame)(implicit spark:SparkSession) : DataFrame = {    
    // needed to use $ to generate ColumnName
    import sparkSession.implicits._

    df.select($"i")
  }
}
```

I don't really understand why we need an instance of `SparkSession` just to import  these implicit conversions. I would rather like to do something like :

```
object Transformations {  
  import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits._ // does not work

  def selectI(df:DataFrame) : DataFrame = {    
    df.select($"i")
  }
}
```

Is there an elegant solution for this problem? My use of the implicits is not limited to `$` but also `Encoders`, `.toDF()` etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I don't really understand why we need an instance of SparkSession just to import these implicit conversions. I would rather like to do something like

Because every `Dataset` exists in a scope of specific `SparkSession` and a single Spark application can have multiple active `SparkSession`.

Theoretically some of the `SparkSession.implicits._` could exist separately from the session instance like:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.implicits._   // For let's say `$` or `Encoders`
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.implicits._  // For toDF
```

but it would have a significant impact on the user code.

Comment: I would add, that the only abstract member of `SQLImplicits`  is an instance of `SQLContext`, so there is really no viable workaround even for implicits which don't strictly depend on as specific `SQLContetxt`. Otherwise, nice answer.